# Multiply all td values(numbers) from a table with 3.8

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-table

My table is here http://jsfiddle.net/wqk7Lauz/

All I need is to have all values from td:nth-of-type(3) multiplied with 3.8 on page load.

HTML

```js
$('td:nth-of-type(3)').text(parseFloat($('td:nth-of-type(3)').text()) * 3.8)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered mydatatable table-hover display responsive nowrap">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preço por 1000</th>
      <th>Quantidade mínima</th>
      <th>Quantidade máxima</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Product </td>
      <td>
        R$1.86
      </td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>10000</td>
      <td>S1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Product </td>
      <td>
        R$3.98
      </td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>S1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, you just need to use the callback version of `text` so you're only handling the text of each individual element, and remove the `R$` at the beginning:

```
$('td:nth-of-type(3)').text(function() {
    return parseFloat($(this).text().replace("R$", "")) * 3.8;
});
```

Example:

```js
$('td:nth-of-type(3)').text(function() {
    return parseFloat($(this).text().replace("R$", "")) * 3.8;
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered mydatatable table-hover display responsive nowrap">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preço por 1000</th>
      <th>Quantidade mínima</th>
      <th>Quantidade máxima</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Product </td>
      <td>
        R$1.86
      </td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>10000</td>
      <td>S1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Product </td>
      <td>
        R$3.98
      </td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>S1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to add back the `R$`, and perhaps limit the result to a specific number of places, you can do that with string concatenation and `toFixed`:

```
$('td:nth-of-type(3)').text(function() {
    return "R$" + (parseFloat($(this).text().replace("R$", "")) * 3.8).toFixed(2);
});
```

Example:

```js
$('td:nth-of-type(3)').text(function() {
    return "R$" + (parseFloat($(this).text().replace("R$", "")) * 3.8).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered mydatatable table-hover display responsive nowrap">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Preço por 1000</th>
      <th>Quantidade mínima</th>
      <th>Quantidade máxima</th>
      <th>Descrição</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Product </td>
      <td>
        R$1.86
      </td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>10000</td>
      <td>S1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Product </td>
      <td>
        R$3.98
      </td>
      <td>1000</td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>S1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting NaN maybe because of the currency symbol? Also result must have 2 decimals. Thank you !!!! http://jsfiddle.net/wqk7Lauz/6/

Comment: @kkossasa - Yes, `parseFloat("R$123")` is `NaN` because `parseFloat` stops at the first non-digit, non-`.`, which is `R`. *"Also result must have 2 decimals"* Great, the second code example above should do it. :-)

Comment: You can avoid the use of `$(this).text()` if you use the second argument provided to the `text()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Hi change your script function with this

```
$(".table tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){ //Loop
 //alert($(this).text()) 
  var thrdtd = $(this).text(); //Getting value of td

  onlyno = thrdtd.replace('R$', ''); // Removing R$

  //akert(thrdtd);
  $(this).text('R$ '+ parseFloat(onlyno * 3.8).toFixed(2)) // Adding R$ and also multiplying at the same time and update that result to td again

});
```

In this first i am getting value of every third td value through loop

```
$(".table tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){
```

and then removing character from it before multiplying and then after multiplying i am updating the same td value

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code:

```
$('td:nth-of-type(3)').text("R$" + (parseFloat($(this).text().replace("R$", "")) * 3.8).toFixed(2));
```